# Seeking Metadata for MapQuest Light (OSM) Basemap?

Tags: openstreetmap, metadata, basemap, mapquest

Can anyone direct me to a link that has metadata for a basemap called MapQuest Light (OSM)?

To view the basemap, it can be found at this website:

https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/

Select the drop down and choose MapQuest Light (OSM).

I haven't been able to locate any metadata or any specifics on this basemap.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for responding to my question! If you can point in the direction of official routes for support I'd be happy to pursue them myself.
Unfortunately I can find nothing related to this from MapQuest.

Comment: This would be fine to ask in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).  For which you have just enough rep at 20.

Comment: If this is open data then the place to ask about its metadata may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a Mapbox style developed for Mapquest.  I'd contact Mapbox about it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133138)

Comment: @BERA  No, it actually is an answer to the question.  When Mapquest stopped developing their own map style they started using one that Mapbox developed for them instead (with Mapbox providing the infrastructure too).  This is that style.  Given that Mapbox are a commercial provider the answer here is to ask them under what terms that style can be used.